# Angular Show button after click on a button and function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello i 've put a disabled attribute so that the button will be visible after a function is called. But it doesnt work async. I mean that after the function is called succefully the button is still disabled.

**Html**

```
   //BUTTON THAT CALLS THE FUNCTION

    <ion-buttons slot="end" *ngIf=" item.uid_fk != userDetails.uid">
    <ion-button *ngIf="!item.friend_id" [disabled]="item.busy" (click)="followUser(item)">
    <ion-icon color="primary" name="person-add"></ion-icon>
    <ion-text color="primary"> Believe</ion-text>
    </ion-button>
                                                
    <ion-button *ngIf="item.friend_id" [disabled]="item.busy" (click)="unfollowUser(item)">
    <ion-icon color="secondary" name="person"></ion-icon>
    <ion-text color="secondary"> DisBelieve</ion-text>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-buttons> 

   //BUTTON THAT I WANT TO BE VISIBLE
   <ion-button [disabled]="!isValidThird()" (click)="next(slides, 1)">
    <ion-label>{{translation.next}}</ion-label>
    </ion-button>
```

**TS.**

```
     followUser(item) {
    item.busy = true;
    this.userData.followUser(item.uid, item.username).pipe(
        map((data: any) => {
            item.friend_id = item.uid;
            item.username = item.username;
            item.busy = false;
            if (data.success) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'You Believed ' + item.username,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    backdrop: false,
                    timer: 2500
                })
            }
        })
    ).subscribe()
}

 isValidThird() {
    if (this.userDetails.friend_count>0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I dont want to use  `window.location.reload();` to reload the page. The function works as wanted but it doesnt async.

Comment: please add details of your code. There is not enough here to answer the question

Comment: I think that the answer is to call the FUNCTION() into  ionViewWillEnter() {this.FUNCTION();} like this

Comment: You need to assign a boolean variable to the [disabled] attribute, only n this case the button will change if the value changed.

Comment: you can use this on your button element: `[disabled]="userDetails.friend_count>0 ? true: false"`

Answer (score 0):

What I had to was to put an ngModel value to followUser function and then set the value on the function.
Like this.

```
ts 

 isValid() {
    if (**this.user.friend>0**) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

async followUser(item) {
    item.busy = true;
    **this.user.friend = 1;**
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

`<ion-button expand="block" [disabled]="!isValid()">Next Step`

To this:

`<ion-button expand="block" [disabled]="valid">Next Step`

And in your isValid() function instead of returning the boolean, assign it to the variable.

```
isValid() {
  if (this.user.title) {
    this.valid = true;
  }
  this.valid = false;
}
```

Don't forget to declare valid in your class.

### Update 1:

After some discussion with the questionaire, this is my suggestion:

1. After your async call finished, run the validation like this:

   .subscribe(response => {
   this.isValid()
   })

Keep the rest as suggested in my first answer, and you should be all set.

Comment: You definitely do NOT want to do this as having a function call within you HTML will result in excessive processing/re-rendering in the lifecycle. Additionally, it is possible for this.valid to be mutated outside of function. Better to get isValid and have it as a getter function. However that still won't solve the issue. If OP would post full code, my guess is this approach needs a call to changeDetectionReference,

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I have shared full code. I repeat that the functions (followuser) work. And if userDetails.friend_count is greater than 0 then the button is visible. It has to reload the page async Thats what i am asking

Comment: @JoshuaSanchez please confirm that I understand you correctly: A user can call the function followUser() by klicking the button. This function will add data to userDetails.friendCount. If that friend count is over 0, the button that is currently disabled, should be enabled. Is this what you're going for?

Comment: How am i going to call isValid function? in your answer you 've said to change disabled=!isValid to disabled=valid. How am i going to call isValid? And by 'After your async call finished ' the followUser function right? But the function hasn't a response value.